# Двунаправленный список поменять элементы

Tags: c++

```
struct Spis2
{
int info;
Spis2  *prev, *next;
} *begin, *end, *t, *b, *e;
```

Есть двунаправленный список, нужно написать функцию , которая меняет местами максимальный элемент и второй.Предположим , что max указатель на макс. элемент.

Comment: В чём проблема поменять? Алгорим любого обмена вот `c=a; a=b; b=c;`

Comment: В некоторых случаях возможно и так `a^=b^=a^=b;`. По поводу уместности для указателей - не пробовал, посему, не уверен.

Comment: В этом случае нет смысле менять сами элементы как таковые, с обновлением указателей. Проще поменять местами поля `info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void swap(int* fst, int* snd)  
{  
    int* tmp = fst;
    fst = snd;  
    snd = tmp;  
}  
int* second = begin->next;  
swap(max, second);
```

В чем вообще проблема?

Comment: Простите моя ошибка, нужно поменять не значения, а указатели!

Comment: @AlexStepanov тогда все намного проще

Comment: и каким образом это сделать?

Comment: @AlexStepanov посмотрите ответ, я его поправил

Comment: sm4ll_3gg fst указатель на макс. элемент?

Comment: @AlexStepanov на один из элементов, которые меняем местами. Какой из них макс определяется при вызове функции